# SQL syntax error using PgAdmin3

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert the following data, but Im getting a syntax error for the line "2, docking station ..."

This is the error im getting but I inputed line 1 the exact same way.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Docking"
LINE 4: (2,'Docking Station','AS-0201764-RT','275-4197991-QC-53','Eq...
            ^
********** Error **********
ERROR: syntax error at or near "Docking"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 348


INSERT INTO assets (id, name, asset_tag, asset_serial_number, asset_type, product_descrption, asset_status, warranty_date, warranty_length, employee_id) 
VALUES 
(1,'Monitor','AS-8153000-DP','358-7190353-JD-44', 'Equipment', 'A display screen used to provide visual output from a computer', 'Assigned', '2018-01-08', '1 year', 'ZO-9440’ ),
(2,'Docking Station','AS-0201764-RT','275-4197991-QC-53','Equipment', 'A device in which a laptop computer, smartphone, or other mobile device may be placed for charging','Assigned','2017-07-12','1 year','ZO-9440’),
```

Comment: Need to replace `,` to `;` at the second data value line

Comment: The closing quote for the last token on the first line, `'ZO-9440’` looks like a "high nine" quote rather than a "straight" quote. A high-nine quote isn't a valid delimiter. Looks like you've got the same thing going on at the end of the second `VALUES` line, too.

Comment: Thank you! The error was the "high nine" quote.

Comment: Bob is right: `'ZO-9440’` needs to be `'ZO-9440'`